# Squaring a list, then amending entire thing it into an empty list

Tags: python, list, loops

I'm being asked to square a set list of integers, and cube a set list of integers and floating numbers, then amend each of those lists into two separate empty lists.

I'm using python on jupyter. I'm being limited to the things we've already learned (important point - I've tried using functions we haven't learned yet and the professor would prefer I stay confined to topics we've covered). We've learned to make lists, measure the length of our lists, amend to our lists, and for loops (using rang)e and while loops... the very-basics.

```
x = [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18]
y = [10,8.25,7.5,7,6.5,7,7.5,8.25,10]

# initialize new lists below
xsquared = []

ycubed = []

# loop(s) to compute x-squared and y-cubed below

for item_X in x:
    item_X **= 2

for item_Y in y:
    item_Y **= 3

# Use .append() to add computed values to lists you initialized

xsquared.append(item_X)
print(xsquared)

ycubed.append(item_Y)
print(ycubed)

# Results
```

Actual results:

```
[324]
[1000]
```

Expected results:

```
[4, 16, 36, 64, 100.... 324]
[1000, 561.515625, 421.875.... 1000]
```

Comment: append to the result lists in your loops. Or use list comprehensions

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehension, you can do this as:

```
x_squared = [item_x**2 for item_x in x]
y_cubed = [item_y**3 for item_y in y]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only appending the last result. If you want to stick with the topics you have covered, you should use `for` loops:

```
x = [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18]
y = [10,8.25,7.5,7,6.5,7,7.5,8.25,10]

xsquared = []
ycubed = []

for item_X in x: 
    xsquared.append(item_X ** 2)

for item_Y in y: 
    ycubed.append(item_Y ** 3)
```

However, the simplest way is to use a list comprehension:

```
x = [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18]
y = [10,8.25,7.5,7,6.5,7,7.5,8.25,10]

xsquared = [n ** 2 for n in x]
ycubed = [n ** 3 for n in x]
```

The output in both cases:

```
print(xsquared)
print(ycubed)
```

---

```
[4, 16, 36, 64, 100, 144, 196, 256, 324]
[1000, 561.515625, 421.875, 343, 274.625, 343, 421.875, 561.515625, 1000]
```

Comment: I'm going to need to use things we've covered, so I can't use the list comprehension method (thanks for that, though). If I wanted to have those append functions at the bottom of the code, so that all I have to type is something like 

"ycubed.append(item_Y)"

without the ** 3, is there a way to do that? Kind of like what I had, but appending the entire list (not just the last number).

Comment: @LearningSlowly No, there's no way to "append the entire list" without creating a copy of the list and then extending the original list, which is a super convoluted way of doing it. The given approach is the simplest and the best.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to avoid list comprehensions or `map()`

```
x = [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18] 
y = [10,8.25,7.5,7,6.5,7,7.5,8.25,10]
x2 = []
y3 = []
for i in x:
    x2.append(i*i)
for i in y:
    y3.append(i**3)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Curious - is there a way to have the for loops set "i" equal to the list I'm going for? Then adding that entire i list to my empty xsquared list? I'm asking in case my professor would prefer I do this in steps (empty list, THEN for loops, THEN append functions). If not, I'll just include them both in the same block.